# How can I use awk command in the example below to store the values?

Tags: awk

I want to sum from position 68 to 81 based on the Value on the position 67 that is `D` in the following file:

```
10010001602171813800899901000000000101211000002007-05-130005316347D000000000000800 000000002007-05-18x?0000000000
10010001602171813800899901000000000201211000002007-05-130748402438C000000000000800 000000002007-05-18x?0000000000
10010001602171813800899901100000000101211000002007-05-130005316347D000000000000800 000000002007-05-18x?0000000000
10010001602171813800899901100000000201211000002007-05-130748402438C000000000000800 000000002007-05-18x?0000000000
```

And I want to have another sum from position 68 to 81 based on the Value on the position 67 that is `C`, i.e

```
s1 =1600 (based on D)
s2 =1600 (based on C)
```

I used

```
grep "^1" file.txt | \
  awk '{s[substr($0,67,68-67)]+=substr($0,68,83-68)} 
       END { for (i in s) { print i, s[i] }}'
```

and got the sum as

```
C 1596678
D 1596678
```

but I want to store the above two values in two separate variables, like A should hold 1596678 and B should hold 1596678.

Comment: something like `read -r _ a _ b <<<$(grep "^1" file.txt | awk '{s[substr($0,67,68-67)]+=substr($0,68,83-68)} END { for (i in s) { print i, s[i] }}'); echo $a $b` ?

Comment: it give the output for the variable $a and the output of $b is empty

Comment: also can i remove the print statement

Comment: Why couldn't you have created an example where column 3 is D and you want to sum columns 5to 8 or similar? See [ask] and in particular the part about creating a [mcve] (emphasis on Minimal in this case).

Comment: You don't need grep when you're using awk.

`grep "^1" file | awk '{foo}'`

is the same as just calling:

`awk '/^1/{foo}' file`

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP told `mapfile` is not working so putting another command here.

```
numbers=$(grep "^1" | awk '{array[substr($0,67,1)]+=substr($0,68,15)+0} END{for(i in array){print i,array[i]}}')
for (( i=0; i<${#numbers[@]}; i++ )); do echo ${numbers[i]}; done
```

---

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps. Using `mapfile` and `awk` and storing values into an array here.

```
mapfile -t array1 < <(grep "^1" Input_file | awk '{array[substr($0,67,1)]+=substr($0,68,15)+0} END{for(i in array){print i,array[i]}}')
```

Now if you want to see individual value of array you could get by doing:

```
echo "${array1[1]}"
D 160
```

AND

```
echo "${array1[0]}"
C 160
```

***NOTE:*** If there are more values in array from `awk` then you need not to use many variables for it array should take care of it. Also in case you only need the integer values then change from `{print i,array[i]` to `{print array[i]` in above code too.

Comment: i get a -ksh: mapfile: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: @user9794957, it is working fine for me, which OS it is for you? Also `mapfile` man page shows it is bash utility so it should be there. Let me know on same.

Comment: @user9794957, only  `awk` and `grep` is working fine for you? without `<(` brackets let me know on same?

Comment: operating system is linux

Comment: it give me C 1596678
D 1596678

Comment: @user9794957, ok try my EDIT command and let me know then? Also change from `print i,array[i]}` to `print array[i]}` in case you want to only get numeric values in bash's array. Let me know.

Comment: it works i think as it give me a output of C 1596678 D 1596678 but when i am not sure whether the output is because of the echo or the print statement

Comment: want to remove the print statement in the command but am getting a error is that possible that i can remove the print statement and excute..

Answer (score 0):

So .. first off, array elements ARE separate variables. And at any point in the END block of your awk script, you can do something like:

```
A=s["C"]
B=s["D"]
```

But without knowing that your input data is limited to these two characters in column 67, you can't know how many variables to assign. Generally it's not such a good idea to write your code to be flexibly with varying input data, rather than to assume that your data will always have particular content.  That "C" or "D" is part of your *data*, not your *schema*.

That said ... fixing the math in your original awk, I came up with:

```
$ awk -v n=67 '
/^1/ {
  s[substr($0,n,1)]+=substr($0,n+1,15)
}
END {
  for(i in s) printf "%s %d\n",i,s[i]
}
' input.txt
```

The idea here is the `n` is where we want to start paying attention to data (i.e. it provides the key of the array), and the following 15 characters are the numbers to sum.

Alternately, if your `awk` is actually `gawk`, it might be clearer to use the FIELDWIDTHS variable for fixed-width fields:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN{
  FIELDWIDTHS="66 1 15 1"
}
/^1/ {
  s[$2]+=$3
}
END {
  for(i in s) printf "%s %d\n",i,s[i]
}
' input.txt
```

With the input data you've provided, both of these result in:

```
C 1600
D 1600
```

Note that I'm going with a solution that matches your results (i.e. each $3 has a value of `800`) rather than your question (where they had a value of `8`). Feel free to adjust this solution to your actual field widths as required.